# Receiving 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "sudo"' when trying to create a user in postgres db

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to learn how to configure and setup a Postgres database, I am using WSL/Ubuntu. I am following along with this [guide](https://harshityadav95.medium.com/postgresql-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-6dc751ac1ff3). I'm at the point where I am to create a user but I keep receiving a syntax error and I'm struggling to figure out how I can continue.

```
postgres=# sudo -u postgres createuser rncongi;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sudo"
LINE 1: sudo -u postgres createuser rncongi;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` is a Linux command, not a SQL command that you can run from within `psql`.

Additionally `createuser` is *also* a command line tool (that needs to run *outside* of `psql), **not** a [SQL command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)

But as you are already logged into `psql` as the superuser, use the [SQL command `create user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html) to create  new user

```
postgres=# create user rncongi;
```